# How can I show attribute value with check Box in Yii 2 GridView

Tags: checkbox, yii

i like to put mission_id in checkbox

```
$req = 'select c.mission_id as mission_id, c.user_id as user_id from order c';

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => $req,
    ]);

    return $this->render('factures', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

in _index.php

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'mission_id',
        'user_id',

    ],
]); ?>
```

This it's ok, but when i use checkbox, it s KO : Trying to get property of non-object

```
[
            'attribute' => 'id',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="'.$data->mission_id.'" />Mission : '.$data->mission_id;
            },
        ],
```

Your help please

Comment: U have to use kartik grid..

Answer (score 0):

a some response : Trying to get property of non-object with :

```
                [
            'attribute' => 'id',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($model) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" name="chk_group" value="'.$model->mission_id.'" />Mission : '.$model->mission_id;
            },
            ],
```